# Receiving ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSION_TO_CORRECT_TABS from Rest API; where is this permission configured?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I have an application that's been running just fine for a couple of years.  Recently I'm getting the error message ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSION_TO_CORRECT_TABS when attempting to add tabs to a newly added signer using a POST .../recipients/[recip-id]/tabs request to the REST API.  I'd guess this permission is configured in the DocuSign console, but I'm not finding it there.  Anyone know what controls this?

Comment: Hmm not sure off the top of my head, but one thing you can try is retrieving your account settings or user settings through the API to see if that yields any info.  Actually, I also just found this which is related to the Classic Console UI.  Do a search for "correct" on this page and you'll see the setting:  https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-user-permissions-settings

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ergin.  Ours is un-checked, which should allow, if I read it correctly; the reference to the "tag palette" suggests it might refer more to a UI.

Comment: Will try accessing account settings through the API; good lead!  Let you know what happens...